# Trouble with TYPO3 RTE CKEditor and Tags

Tags: typo3, ckeditor, typo3-extensions

In the RichTextEditor of the TYP03 backend, I want to use the tag `address`.

When I look at the default configurations `vendor/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml` I see `address` in the list of `allowTags`. This is imported in by my extension, like every other extension that is created by the Sitepackage Builder.

I added the extension as Page TSconfig resource of the Site.

When I have a look at the Page TSconfig section, I can see the `extension_key` is set correctly.

```
 RTE

  default

    preset = extension_key
```

So I see no reason why I can't use the `address` tag, but when I add the tag in the source tab of the RTE, it gets converted to a paragraph(`p`) tag.

So

```
<address>
   Damn I want a address here!
</address>
```

becomes

```
<p>
   Damn I want a address here!
</p>
```

I have no idea why.

So I have two questions:

What is the reason I can't use the address tag by default?

How can I achieve that I can use the address tag?

I also have tried to append the `RTE/Default.yaml` by that line `allowTags: "address"`.

If it is possible, I would like to stay in the yaml definition.

### Update:

I think the TypoScript Object Browser seems to be fine:

[image: Values of the object browser]

Thank you for your time

Comment: I guess that `lib.parseFunc` or `lib.parseFunc_RTE` could be involved. 
Can you see from Typoscript Object Browser the value of `lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks` or `lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags`  or `lib.parseFunc_RTE.denyTags` ?

Comment: For me, it seems to be fine in the object browser. I updated the Question

Comment: Funny thing: on TYPO3 11, after adding `lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks:=addToList(address)` the following behavior occurs: you can add `<address>` in the source code of an RTE area, but it will be reverted to a `<p>`.. nonetheless, in the frontend, the `<address>` tag is present!

I guess that on TYPO3 12 your problem could be related to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/100861

Comment: hmm yeah... I think it is funny if you don't need the feature :D